# Efficiant loading via filter with Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have several mapbox datasets, each with a collection of features located in different *cities*. Each feature has a field named `city` that contains the city the feature is located in (e.g. `city = "new york"`).  In mapbox studio I have a style with layers made from each of those datasets. I want to load a map with it's bounding box containing all features with `city == "new york"`(fit map view to features bbox). How can I accomplish that, **preferably** without ever loading features that don't satisfy `city=="new york"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a basemap that contains all the cities, but when you load the map in mapbox-gl-js, you want to filter them to just one particular city.

You do this by calling:

`map.setFilter('my-cities-layer', ['==', ['get', 'city'], 'new york']);`

There isn't really a simple way of filtering *all* layers to only include data with that tag, though.

Comment: Thanks Steve! In general, it's worth noting that the GL JS expression-based solution outlined here is essentially equivalent to the Studio-based solution outlined in a previous answer, but the decision about whether to apply the filter in Studio or on the client side with GL JS will depend on the specifics of your implementation. If you do want to visually filter the city data at runtime, the expression-based filtering is a good choice (this example in our docs shows a use case quite similar to what you are looking for: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-markers-by-input/).

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming that as a programming site, a programming answer was being asked for. Non-programming questions are off-topic for SO (although I think non-programming *answers* may be ok).

Comment: Wow, Thanks Steve and Mapbox Support! With your solution and the fit-to-bounds requirement, this is the solution I currently use: https://gist.github.com/guy-kdm/a6e93c190b267582f1d859e08ef0df5f
I think this isn't ideal, I'd like the map first render to be with correct bounds, not on "load" when it already rendered, and for some reason the geometry.coordinates property isn't typed.

Comment: Ah, this requirement wasn't stated. Perhaps start a new question for "how do I manipulate the style before the map loads".

Comment: Thanks @SteveBennett, this is what i meant by "...with it's bounding box containing all features with city == "new york"... in the question text. I'll edit the phrasing to make it clearer. Is this fit-to-bounds behavior possible to accomplish? Thanks loads again, spent lots of time on it!

Comment: No, not really via this method.

Answer (score 1):

After selecting the relevant layer in Mapbox Studio, select the property whose visibility you would like to control. For example, suppose that you are interested in showing a text field for each of these features in your dataset (the same logic could also be applied to icon images). Once this property of the layer is selected, click on the "Style with data conditions" option in the layer editor. You will then be prompted to choose a data field (which in your case will be `city`) and subsequently prompted to set values for this data field (which in your case will be `new york`).